# Delaunay triangulation of monotone Polygon

Tags: polygon, triangulation, delaunay

I have searched the whole internet and scientific databases for a paper on Delaunay Triangulation of monotone Polygons. I'm not searching for arbitrary Triangulation of Polygons, only for Delaunay triangulation. Does anybody know such a publication, where monotone Polygons are Delaunay triangulated? Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delaunay triangulation applies to a set of points, not to a given shape (such as a polygon).
You're looking for constrained delaunay triangulation if you have a specific shape to triangulate...
I implemented the Bowyer-Watson algorithm, with constraints to delaunay-triangulate a given polygon (not necessarily monotone).
My implementation is a part of [OgreProcedural](http://code.google.com/p/ogre-procedural/).

I read the following papers on the subject before implementing it :

- http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~samuelp/del_project.html
- http://www.cg.tuwien.ac.at/hostings/cescg/CESCG-2004/web/Domiter-Vid/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But is there any performance gain (in terms of complexity) if the polygon is monotone?